# How to perform bulk insert when we have identity column in the table

Tags: sql-server, text-files, bulkinsert

I excluded values of identity column of the table in the text file i used to load. This resulted error while loading. Please let me know how to deal with this scenario.

Comment: Yeah man, we need more details concerning what you are trying to do and what the error is that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Your source csv file should include all columns, even the identity column.

The destination table with the identity column will create its own values when you bulk upload and it will ignore the column in your source CSV file unless you specify the KEEPIDENTITY property.

See [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)